# Is there any way to recover my sudo power?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sudo, ubuntu-12.04

I created a new user and changed the ssh config. I forgot to add root permission to the newly created user.

Now I need to undo my changes in ssh config. Is that possible without any sudo command?

Comment: Yes, by logging in as `root`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have acess to the 'su' command, you can change to the root user without sudo permissions if you know the password of the root user. Use it like `su root`.